# Error: Invalid First Argument

Tags: r, dplyr, rsqlserver

I'm getting an "invalid first argument" error for the following. However, con is an actual connection and is set up properly. So what does this error actually refer to?

```
library(dplyr)
con <- RSQLServer::src_sqlserver("***", database = "***")

myData <- con %>%
  tbl("table") %>%
  group_by( work_dt, campaign, ad_group, matchtype, keyword ) %>%
  select( work_dt, campaign, ad_group, matchtype, keyword, impressions, clicks, cost ) %>%
  filter(site_id %in% c(6932,6946,6948,6949,6951,6952,6953,6954,
                        6955,6964,6978,6979,7061,7260,7272,7329,
                        7791,7794,7850,7858,7983)) %>% 
  filter(work_dt >= as.Date("2014-10-01 00:00:00") & work_dt < as.Date("2014-10-02 00:00:00")) %>%
  summarise(
    sum_impressions = sum(impressions),
    sum_clicks = sum(clicks),
    sum_cost = sum(cost),
  ) %>%
  collect()
```

This code produces:

```
Error in exists(name, env) : invalid first argument



exists("con")

> exists(con)
Error in exists(con) : invalid first argument
> exists("con")
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: I'm using the RSQLServer package, not RODBC, so I don't think that query is relevant in this cast.   ("Error: could not find function "dbGetQuery"")

Comment: So dbSendQuery(con, "select * from table"). The point is, is your connection working as expected.

Comment: Yes, it's working as expected and I can pull data if I remove the summarize() section of the dplyr code.